# Auto inernal links with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a jQuery script which will create auto internal links in a single web page. I have almost done it. I am stuck with the link itself is converting.

If I am finding the string in a web page, is there a way to find in tag of the text?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href]").each(function()
   { 
      $link=this.href;
      $text=this.text;

       $('*:contains("'+$text+'")').each(function(){
     if($(this).children().length < 1){ 
                $(this).text($(this).text().replace($text, '<a href="'+$link+'" target="_blank">'+$text+'</a>')); 
      } 

        });
   });

  });
```

Help me it will be helpful for all blogger blogs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add a `target="_blank"` to all your links? If so, you can do it as easily as

```
$("a[href]").attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: `$("a[href]")` what does this selector mean?

Comment: it means - all anchor `<a>` tags with a `href` attribute

Comment: is `<a>` valid without `href` attribute?!

Comment: So why I see so often `<a href='#'>`? I'm sorry for annoying you with my questions...

Comment: No probs. :) The # destination is supposed to be used for going to another anchor in the same page. i.e. href="#form" etc..